# Quarto: Can't render greek letters in equations

Tags: latex, r-markdown, quarto

This [Github repo](https://github.com/albersonmiranda/monografia), hosts a .qmd file of my dissertation template. In the last few lines of it there's an inline equation like this `$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + e_i$`. Thing is, the greek letter `\beta` doesn't render.

I think may be a conflict in my `preamble.tex` but I couldn't figure that out.

**Edit:** 1 minute later I figured out that if I set a font that has greek letters, as in `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` it works. I don't know what's the default Quarto font, but maybe that's it.

Comment: It works with the default Quarto font. Maybe you are right about conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a font in `preamble.tex` did the trick: `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`